# How to apply a :not selector and all its descendants

Tags: css, sass

I'm using a text editor plugin with its own styles but inside I'm rendering a Mapbox map. The problem is that the editor's styles are messing up Mapbox's.

The text editor styles are in `arx-content-custom.scss` and this is how I'm using them:

```
#association-content-row {
  @import 'arx-content-custom';
}
```

So that it applies to the specific `#association-content-row` container where the editor is loaded and not the entire page.

I tried excluding the Mapbox element like this:

```
#association-content-row :not(.mapboxgl-map) {
  @import 'arx-content-custom';
}
```

But the styles keep getting applied to the map. What can I do?

edit: let me provide some HTML to exemplify my case.

I have a container with many descendants. I'd like to apply `arx-content-custom.scss` styles to these. But `.mapboxgl-map` is also within `#association-content-row` so styles are getting applied and overriding the way some elements in the map looks, like links, buttons, spacing... I'd like to exclude `.mapboxgl-map` **and all its descendants** from the scope where those `arx-content-custom` styles are getting applied.

```
<div id="association-content-row">
    <div class="row1">
        <div>
            <button></button>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href=""></a>
    <div class="mapboxgl-map">
        <div>
            <button></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2"></div>
    <form action="" class="myform"></form>
</div>
```

For instance, `arx-content-custom` styles should apply to the `button` within `.row1` but not the button in the map.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provide enough information to say what's the problem (i.e., no HTML). I will try and guess what could be the problem. I doubt it's SCSS (i.e., `@import`) that is causing this, I think it's your HTML structure.

**1. If you have an HTML structure like this:**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

WRONG:

```
#parent:not(#a) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

RIGHT:

```
#parent :not(#a) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

RIGHT:

```
#parent > :not(#a) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**2. If you have an HTML structure like this:**

```
<div id="association-content-row" class="mapboxgl-map">first</div>
<div id="association-content-row">second</div>
<div id="association-content-row">third</div>
```

WRONG:

```
#association-content-row :not(.mapboxgl-map) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

RIGHT:

```
#association-content-row:not(.mapboxgl-map) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Let me know if this is helpful.

---

**EDIT:**

```css
#association-content-row > :not(.mapboxgl-map) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="association-content-row">
  <div class="row1">
    <div>
      <div>APPLY</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mapboxgl-map">
    <div>
      <div>DO NOT APPLY</div>
      <div>
        <div>DO NOT APPLY</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>DO NOT APPLY</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">APPLY</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added an edit with some HTML. I'm not asking just about one descendant, for all its descendants as well. Think of it this way: I have a big component with its own global styles and then the map plugin with its own global styles. The problem is that since the map HTML is also within the other component then those styles are overriding the map's.